# nhibernate select n random unique records

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

This has been asked before many times but i couldnt find a conclusive answer to this. Can anyone assist

I want to be able to query my database (will my sqlServer AND mysql) using nhibernate in order to get X number of rows. these numbers need to be unique. I am selecting 250 out of 350 so my odds are high that i will have duplicates (because random doent imply unique)

This needs to work for both mysql and sql server.

since I am selecting over 70% of the table already, i dont mind selecting all the records, and using LINQ to pul out the 250 unique values (if this is possible)

whatever has the least impact on my system overhead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order your results using RAND() or NEWID() and select the top 250 - the results will be distinct and random, in terms of efficiency, this will be more efficient than retrieving all 350 results and then ordering them randomly in code - IF YOU IGNORE CACHING

However if you do cache the results, it will probably be significantly more efficient over time to retrieve the 350 results into a cache (preferrably using NHibernate's second level cache) and then sort them in code using something like:

```
var rand = new Random();    
var results = Session.CreateCriteria<MyClass>()
   .SetCacheable(true)
   .List()
   .OrderBy(x => rand.Next());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the distinct, add **.Distinct()** before the **.ToList();**

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered yourself.

A full-table query for 350 records is going to put less strain on the server than a complex randomizing and paging query for 250 (that is usually done by appending a uniqueidentifier to rows in an inner query and then sorting using it. Your can't do that with LINQ)

Your can even cache the results for and then randomize the list in memory each time to get 250 different records.